# Alternative to NSZombie

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory, nszombie

I'm trying to debug an EXC_BAD_ACCESS crash using NSZombie. My app creates lots of large objects though and with NSZombie enabled they aren't getting released causing the app to crash in seconds. This means I can't even cause the EXC_BAD_ACCESS crash before the app crashes due to low memory.

Is there an alternative? Can I enable NSZombie on specific file instead of the entire project? How else could I debug this crash (I know it's caused by UIGestureRecognizer but I use them a lot so it doesn't narrow down the issue significantly).

Thanks.

**Edit:
Thanks for the advice. I think I may have solved the issue and will report back after more testing.**

**Edit 2: Sovled the issue myself but selected the answer which seems like it would be a good solution to any similar issues in the future.**

Comment: The simulator can handle a lot more memory usage than a real device. Can you try it on the simulator?

Comment: @rmaddy No luck with that either. It allocates about 100mb of memory and crashes.

Comment: If you seem to be having trouble with zombies the first thing to do is to run Analyzer and meticulously work through the warnings produced.  There's a good chance it will find your problem.

Comment: @HotLicks I think I may have actually solved it! Going to do some more testing before confirming though as it wasn't easy to reproduce.

Comment: @kmcgrady in your dealloc, you might be able to get away with replacing the isa of your object with a pointer to the zombie class to achieve single file zombie checking.  Maybe.  Haven't tried it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All I can think of is implementing it manually; create a proxy container that holds an object of type `id` and nominates that as `-forwardingTargetForSelector:` as well as getting it to respond to `-isKindOfClass:`, etc.

Disable ARC for the proxy and have it retain itself during `init` and check its own `retainCount` when nominating a forwarding target.

If the count is 1 then raise an exception or log a warning or whatever.

Have suspect classes wrap themselves in and return a proxy as the last line of their unit.

For possible bonus points, store `[NSThread callStackSymbols]` somewhere (probably on disk) during the proxy's unit so you can at least find out where the incorrectly managed object was created.

Comment: Very interesting idea. I'm going to look into it now.

Comment: Fortunately I found the issue through trial error about 15 mins after you posted this. I guess the fear of trying to implement it spurred me on! Great idea though so thank you.

Answer (score -3):

NSZombies was/is for apps that use their own memory management. If your app uses ARC then this won't help.

Create a new Breakpoint: All Exceptions

That should usually show you where you trigger the bad access.

Comment: Thanks, I'm trying this now - and you're right I'm using ARC.

Comment: This is not true. NSZombies is perfectly fine to use with ARC.

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't help. The exception breakpoint didn't catch it any earlier.

Comment: Setting an exception breakpoint won't help in the case of an EXC_BAD_ACCESS.

Comment: NSZombie can be used any time it's possible to reference a deallocated object, which is perfectly possible under ARC. ARC doesn't get rid of retains/releases/allocs/deallocs/autoreleases, it simply adds them in for you.